# python pandas to_csv appending mode generate unwanted unknown rows

Tags: python

using to_csv appending mode generates unwanted unknown rows.

For example:

```
check = [0,0,0]
df = pd.DataFrame([check])
df.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)
df = pd.DataFrame([check])
df.to_csv('test.csv', mode='a', index=False)
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
```

returns
   `0   1   2
    0   0   0   0
    1   0   1   2
    2   0   0   0`

where the 1 0 1 2 is unwanted and unknown extra row.

What is the problem here?

Comment: Why are you writing to the csv twice? The row with `1 0 1 2` is the header being written twice.

Comment: It's just a small dataset. so I just use csv for simplicity.

Comment: I did not ask why you're using a csv. I asked why you're writing to it twice. Anyway, glad you solved it on your own.

Comment: @AdityaK sorry, not reading your comment carefully. It's just a lazy example..While in most of appending mode example, I saw people just using without header=None..., which will lead to the problem with header written into file as a row..

Answer (score 0):

Found that the extra unwanted row `1 0 1 2` is the columns' name.
Then I just tried following

```
check = [0,0,0]
df = pd.DataFrame([check])
df.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)
df = pd.DataFrame([check])
df.to_csv('test.csv', mode='a', index=False, header=False)
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
```

returns

```
    0   1   2
0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0
```

with `header=False` to ignore the header/columns'name, then it returns what I want.